# Sklearn changing string class label to int

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a pandas dataframe and I'm trying to change the values in a given column which are represented by strings into integers. For instance:

```
df = index    fruit   quantity   price 
         0    apple          5    0.99
         1    apple          2    0.99
         2   orange          4    0.89
         4   banana          1    1.64
       ...
     10023     kiwi         10    0.92
```

I would like it to look at:

```
df = index    fruit   quantity   price 
         0        1          5    0.99
         1        1          2    0.99
         2        2          4    0.89
         4        3          1    1.64
       ...
     10023        5         10    0.92
```

I can do this using

```
df["fruit"] = df["fruit"].map({"apple": 1, "orange": 2,...})
```

which works if I have a small list to change, but I'm looking at a column with over 500 different labels. Is there any way of changing this from a `string` to a an `int`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html) and then convert to [`categorical`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html) if necessary:

```
df.fruit = pd.factorize(df.fruit)[0]
print (df)
   fruit  quantity  price
0      0         5   0.99
1      0         2   0.99
2      1         4   0.89
3      2         1   1.64
4      3        10   0.92
```

---

```
df.fruit = pd.Categorical(pd.factorize(df.fruit)[0])
print (df)
  fruit  quantity  price
0     0         5   0.99
1     0         2   0.99
2     1         4   0.89
3     2         1   1.64
4     3        10   0.92

print (df.dtypes)
fruit       category
quantity       int64
price        float64
dtype: object
```

Also if need count from `1`:

```
df.fruit = pd.Categorical(pd.factorize(df.fruit)[0] + 1)
print (df)
  fruit  quantity  price
0     1         5   0.99
1     1         2   0.99
2     2         4   0.89
3     3         1   1.64
4     4        10   0.92
```

Comment: categoricals by definition factorize; no reason to do it directly

Comment: @Jeff - I dont understand - do you think output of `factorize` is `category` by design? `print (type(pd.factorize(pd.Series(['apple','apple','orange', 'banana']))[0]))` return `numpy array` and [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html#factorizing-values) (last Note) describe how to cast to categorical - it seems after `factorize`. Or something missing? Thanks.

Comment: you don't need to factorize at all, just cast to category and use the codes ; these are the factorization: directly using factorize is not necessary

Answer (score 35):

You can use [sklearn.preprocessing](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html)

```
from sklearn import preprocessing

le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit(df.fruit)
df['categorical_label'] = le.transform(df.fruit)
```

Transform labels back to original encoding.

```
le.inverse_transform(df['categorical_label'])
```

Answer (score 8):

you can use [factorize](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html) method:

```
In [13]: df['fruit'] = pd.factorize(df['fruit'])[0].astype(np.uint16)

In [14]: df
Out[14]:
   index  fruit  quantity  price
0      0      0         5   0.99
1      1      0         2   0.99
2      2      1         4   0.89
3      4      2         1   1.64
4  10023      3        10   0.92

In [15]: df.dtypes
Out[15]:
index         int64
fruit        uint16
quantity      int64
price       float64
dtype: object
```

alternatively you can do it this way:

```
In [21]: df['fruit'] = df.fruit.astype('category').cat.codes

In [22]: df
Out[22]:
   index  fruit  quantity  price
0      0      0         5   0.99
1      1      0         2   0.99
2      2      3         4   0.89
3      4      1         1   1.64
4  10023      2        10   0.92

In [23]: df.dtypes
Out[23]:
index         int64
fruit          int8
quantity      int64
price       float64
dtype: object
```